# Are playlist videos supposed to autoplay even when autoplay is disabled for the playlist?

Tags: youtube

Whenever I watch a video from someone's playlist, if I'm viewing the video in full screen, and the video ends, then the next video in the playlist immediately starts playing.

In the playlist bar at the bottom of the video page, I have both "autoplay" and "shuffle" set to OFF, so is it still supposed to continue autoplaying the playlist? I've already cleared my cookies and cache, but neither fixed it.

People [appear to have been complaining about this problem](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/archive/CCfbMG6Xq3I) at least two years ago. Is anyone else still experiencing this at the moment?

If this is normal behavior, then can anyone suggest a fix? Is the only way to fix this is to remove `&list=` part from the URL?

Comment: This question got obsoleted with the removal of an autoplay setting for playlists (it got replaced with repeat playlist)